# How to get around some rounding errors?

Tags: math, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, epsilon

I have a method that deals with some geographic coordinates in .NET, and I have a struct that stores a coordinate pair such that if 256 is passed in for one of the coordinates, it becomes 0. However, in one particular instance a value of approximately 255.99999998 is calculated, and thus stored in the struct. When it's printed in ToString(), it becomes 256, which should not happen - 256 should be 0. I wouldn't mind if it printed 255.9999998 but the fact that it prints 256 when the debugger shows 255.99999998 is a problem. Having it both store and display 0 would be even better.

Specifically there's an issue with comparison. 255.99999998 is sufficiently close to 256 such that it should equal it. What should I do when comparing doubles? use some sort of epsilon value?

---

EDIT: Specifically, my problem is that I take a value, perform some calculations, then perform the opposite calculations on that number, and I need to get back the original value exactly.

Comment: using epsilon is the only legal method of comparing floating point values. abs(a - b) <= epsilon

Comment: It's perfectly legal to compare two floats with ==, hence why hardly any compiler complains about it.  However, the tiniest rounding error can cause the two values not to be equal when math says they should be, which is why it's not recommended if you value your sanity.

Comment: If you really just need to get the original value back exactly, can't you just store it, or some info about the original calculation process along with the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the epsilon approach, but the epsilon is typically a fudge to get around the fact that floating-point arithmetic is lossy.

You might consider avoiding binary floating-points altogether and use a nice Rational class.

The calculation above was probably destined to be 256 if you were doing lossless arithmetic as you would get with a Rational type.

Rational types can go by the name of Ratio or Fraction class, and are fairly simple to write

Here's one [example](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/35875/download.aspx).
Here's [another](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Mathematics/Arbitrary_Precision_Arithmetic/Arbitrary_Precision_Rationals.aspx)

---

Edit....

To understand your problem consider that when the decimal value 0.01 is converted to a binary representation it cannot be stored exactly in finite memory.  The Hexidecimal representation for this value is 0.028F5C28F5C  where the "28F5C" repeats infinitely.  So even before doing any calculations, you loose exactness just by storing 0.01 in binary format.

Rational and Decimal classes are used to overcome this problem, albeit with a performance cost. Rational types avoid this problem by storing a numerator and a denominator to represent your value.  Decimal type use a binary encoded decimal [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), which can be lossy in division, but can store common decimal values exactly.

For your purpose I still suggest a Rational type.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a problem with how the number is printed, not how it is stored. A `double` has about 15 significant figures, so it can tell 255.99999998 from 256 with precision to spare.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose format strings which should let you display as much of the number as you like.

The usual way to compare doubles for equality is to subtract them and see if the absolute value is less than some predefined epsilon, maybe 0.000001.

Comment: Using the R format specifier rather than the default G caused it show the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide yourself on a threshold under which two values are equal. This amounts to using so-called *fixed point numbers* (as opposed to floating point). Then, you have to perform the round up manually.

I would go with some unsigned type with known size (eg. uint32 or uint64 if they're available, I don't know .NET) and treat it as a fixed point number type mod 256.

Eg.

```
typedef uint32 fixed;

inline fixed to_fixed(double d)
{
    return (fixed)(fmod(d, 256.) * (double)(1 << 24))
}

inline double to_double(fixed f)
{
    return (double)f / (double)(1 << 24);
}
```

or something more elaborated to suit a rounding convention (to nearest, to lower, to higher, to odd, to even). The highest 8 bits of fixed hold the integer part, the 24 lower bits hold the fractional part. Absolute precision is 2^{-24}.

Note that adding and substracting such numbers naturally wraps around at 256. For multiplication, you should beware.